# Automation Studio: create a new automation from PHP

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automationstudio

I'm very new about Salesforce and Marketing Cloud. I've seen it's possible to use two sets APIs (REST and SOAP) to interact with it.
In the official MC documentation Web Services SOAP API are used to interact with the Automations.

However I haven't found anywhere an example or a guide to create via SOAP or REST a full automation with all its part (including all the part for Create New Send Email Activity).

Is it possibile?
Can you please lead me to a working example?

Thanks in advance,
A.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with REST API, you must use the SOAP API to do this:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm

Comment: Your answer is correct that it requires SOAP API. But rather than just a link, could you provide more details in your answer and maybe some quick pointers for actions he can take - even if it is just a list of the appropriate SOAP objects. As it currently is, it is very weak and does not completely answer his question.

Comment: I don't have any code samples for this.  For PHP here is a link to code samples: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/php_code_samples.htm

You are using the automation object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/automation.htm

with also applying AutomationActivity to assign the various tasks to it.  Sorry I don't actually have a setup but the .Net example of creating an automation shows a flow needed.